# Print scope subcollection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have this model and scope

```
categoria: String,
marca: String,
modelo: String,
tipo: String,
detalle: [{
    codigo: String,
    sn: String,
    proveedor: String,
    de: String,
    ubicacion: String,
    observacion: String,
}]
```

I need print this in my HTML I tried this but don't works:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Categoria</th>
        <th>Detalles</th>
        <th>Eliminar</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in stock">
            <td> </td>
            <td>{{item.detalle.codigo}}</td>
            <td>{{item.categoria}}</td>
            <td><a href="#" ng-click="detailStock(item._id)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a></td>
            <td><a href="#" ng-click="deleteStock(item._id)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This code show my item.categoria without problems but don't item.detalle.codigo
how i can print this in my table?

Comment: `detalle` is an array;  you either need to iterate through the array or explicitly access one record in the array.

Answer (score 0):

**`detaille`** is an **`array`**, if you want to access the first item you should do like,

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in stock">
            <td> </td>
            <td>{{item.detalle[0].codigo}}</td>
            <td>{{item.categoria}}</td>
            <td><a href="#" ng-click="detailStock(item._id)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a></td>
            <td><a href="#" ng-click="deleteStock(item._id)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
```

if you want all the items inside the detalle, you should pass the detalle to a function and make the string and return it.